# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -23 error

Tags: java

I wrote a Java program to get JSON list from tumblr. It worked well for 5-6 month but now is giving an error. I am trying to remove 22 useless character from front and 1 semicolon from end.

```
String input = ("good.tumblr.com");

String urlContent = urlReader("http://"+input+"/api/read/json?type=photo&num=0&start=0" );

urlContent=urlContent.substring(22,urlContent.length()-1);
```

But I am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -23
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1967)
    at main.main(main.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

This is the string i will get

```
"  var tumblr_api_read = {"tumblelog":{"title":"","description":"Live Well. Do Good.","name":"good","timezone":"US\/Pacific","cname":false,"feeds":[]},"posts-start":0,"posts-total":2184,"posts-type":"photo","posts":[]};    "
```

https://github.com/Shiva7071007/tumloader_java/tree/master/src

link to whole program .its work in the begging but its not working now. code is not optimized as this was my first java code.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]

Comment: What's unclear about the error message? What is `urlReader`? What does `urlContent` look like after you assign the return value from that function?

Comment: you need to look at the string that was returned. I assume its format changed.

Comment: The problem is, you've got a string index that's out of range.

Comment: View your urlReader method. I suppose the error is coming from there. Your call to substring is using a string different fro  what you wanted.

Comment: Try changing your `http` to `https`. Also in your `urlReader (String _url )` you are reading only last line from response. Maybe it is worth storing all lines in something like `StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(System.lineSeparator())`, you can use it like `js.add(line);` and when you are done with reading all lines and want to get content as string use `sj.toString()`.

Comment: thanks @Pshemo ..it worked. Thanks a lot

Comment: @JarrodRoberson While duplicate explains what problem exception represents, it doesn't explain its cause. Here all info is available since we can see that OP is trying to read from http of `tumblr.com` which is no longer supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `tumblr` moved to `https`. So instead of getting body with JSON structure you are getting only *headers* with redirection information making `String urlContent` hold empty string `""` on which you can't substring starting from `22` till `length()-1`.

To solve this issue simply change your request from `http` to `https`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the string return is blank or shorter then 22 characters. You will need to validate your original string before modifying it